# Twitter bootstrap resets layout past a certain point on mobile

Tags: twitter-bootstrap

The bootstrap layout on my site works perfectly across all browsers, however on a mobile device once scrolling past a certain point the layout changes. and the viewpoints reset.

is this a known thing with bootstrap, and if so: are there any fixes?

Comment: Can't say for sure, but I'd be *really* surprised if this was a problem with bootstrap and not your code.

Comment: It's impossible to guess what's happening. Show your code.